# How to change fixed-top to relative while using bootstrap (html, css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used bootstrap navbar in my html page.

I used "fixed-top" class so my navbar will be fixed to top –

```
<div class="container"> 
  <nav class="nav navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light text-center justify-content-center fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar1</a> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar2</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar3</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

But In mobile presentation I want it to be **position:relative again - How can I achieve that?**

I tried to write this in media queries:

```
.top-fixed{
  position: relative;
}
```

but the navbar stays fixed.

Thanks!

```css
.top-fixed {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <nav class="nav navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light text-center justify-content-center fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar1</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar2</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar3</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 uses !important in almost every line, so one solution is you use it too in your custom css (position: relative !important)

Comment: It’s hard to say without seeing the other selectors as well. Use the css knowledge of selector specificity and the cascade to find why. Also check the browser dev tools, it may help.

Comment: I would use a [mobile detect library](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/) and remove the `fixed-top` class on page load.

Comment: Your class in the HTML and in the CSS **don't match**.

Answer (score 0):

because you try to slyle by class name `.top-fixed` but you don't use it in HTML. Try to add `.top-fixed` class to html element or use `.fixed-top` class in css